# Javascript events and Velocity JS

Tags: javascript, animation, velocity

I am currently learning how to use Velocity JS, but I really don't understand if I am "allowed" to use Javascript events to trigger velocity animations. I don't see any cases of this being done in the documentation.

Comment: Try it and see if it works! Documentations usually do not cover every single use case.

Comment: That's true! Only thing is I feel that since this is so basic that it should appear somewhere in the documentation. I feel as though I am doing something wrong or that there is an encouraged way of triggering velocity animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extensively used events to perform Velocity.js animations. There's nothing wrong or disallowed about doing so.

```
$('.some-element').click(function () {
    $(this).velocity("fadeOut", {
        delay: 500, duration: 1500
    });
});
```